# Retrieve specific values from hashes within an array ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

Noob question here!

I have an array with hashes that looks like this:

```
arr = [{id: 1, name: "Pedro"},{id: 2, name: "Pablo"}]
```

and want to have an array like this:

```
ids = [1,2]
```

I looked into using map or select like this:

```
ids = arr.each.select{|k,v| "id"==k}
```

But I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ids = arr.map { |x| x[:id] }
```

Comment: @Cycle: Several reasons: First `:[` is not a symbol, because `[` is not a valid identifier. Secondly, you cannot use the `&` trick in conjunction with method arguments, because the precise syntax is `method(arg1, arg2, ..., &x)`, where x is an expression that evaluates to a value that has a `to_proc` method. That `to_proc` method is called and the resulting `Proc` object passed as the block parameter to `method`.

Comment: That's fine. I need to retrieve more than one value for example (id and name).

Will it possible?

Comment: @sasikkumare why would it not be possible?